# Regular Expression with oracle

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

Im looking to find a pattern for a  regular expression that start with 3 letters and have 10 numbers after to use it with REGEXP_LIKE in oracle
example for String: ABC1236547890
i need to find the pattern

Comment: "that start with", so '^ is necessary at the beginnign of the regexp.

Comment: thats not very correct because i want only 3 letteres in the start no more and only 10 digits in the end   Example: BVF125478965 is correct and BGHT125478966558 is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> start with 3 letters and have 10 numbers after

You could use **REGEXP_LIKE**:

- `^` - Marks the start
- `[[:alpha:]]` - Alphabet class
- `[[:digit:]]` - Digit class
- `{3}` - Specifies the number of characters
- `$` - Marks the end

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'ABC1234567890' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'AB1234567890123' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'ABCD123456789' STR FROM DUAL
  5  )
  6  SELECT * FROM DATA
  7  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(STR, '^[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]{10}$');

STR
---------------
ABC1234567890

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks very much juste another thing... can i use a select with REGEXP_LIKE because my regulare expression is in another table

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <your_table>  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(<column_name>, '^[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]{10}$');`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select 'abc1234567890' f
from dual)
where 
regexp_like(f, '^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{10}')
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Regular Expression Metacharacters in Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1012) or [Perl-influenced Extensions in Oracle Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix003.htm)

```
^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{10}
```

or

```
^[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]{10}
```

or

```
^[A-Za-z]{3}\d{10}
```

or

```
^\w{3}\d{10}
```

(The last one will also match numbers in the first 3 characters).

If you want it to match the entire string (as mentioned in the comments rather than just to start with the pattern, as described in the question) then just append `$` to the end of any of the above regular expressions

Comment: thanks very much juste another thing... can i use a select with REGEXP_LIKE because my regulare expression is in another table

Comment: The last regex is wrong; not only will it match numbers in addition to letters, it will also match underscores.

Comment: @AbderrahmaneHassani, if you're asking whether you can use a value in a column with `REGEXP_LIKE()`, the answer is yes, e.g. `SELECT a.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON REGEXP_LIKE(a.col1, b.col2);`